# show error message and show query result in html-type email

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I make a email function and in my `$mail->Body` I use html & php code in my `$mail->Body` but I dont get result that I want, I think my html & php code is still error, but I don't get error message showing so I don't know whats wrong with my html&php code. can I show error message for my `$mail->Body` content. I think my code error because when I use simple code for showing data in database, I managed to send an email

this is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("this is my query");

  while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

--I show my query result in `$mail->Body`--


$mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host = "172.16.x.xx"; //my company host
            $mail->PORT = "25";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
            $mail->Username = "myemail@acc.co.id"; //my company email  
            $mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password
            $mail->IsHTML(true); 

            $mail->From = "myemail@acc.co.id";
            $mail->FromName = "ITCareHelpdesk ACC";
            $mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");                            
            $mail->mailtype = "html";
            $mail->Subject = "Weekly monitoring tiket open ITcare"; 
    $mail->Body    ="
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <th>Ticket ID</th>
        <th>Kategori</th>
        <th>Sub kategori</th>                         
        <th>Deskripsi</th>                         
        <th>NPK</th>                         
        <th>Nama</th>                         
        <th>Posisi</th>                         
        <th>Branch</th>                         
        <th>Waktu mulai</th>                         
        <th>Group section</th>                         
        <th>Pic Handle</th>
        <th>Pic Group Section</th>                                                  
      </tr>


      <tr $color>
          <td>$data[TICKET_ID]</td>
          <td>$data[kategori]</td>
          <td>$data[sub_sub_sub_kategori]</td>
          <td>$data[description]</td>
          <td>$data[npk]</td>
          <td>$data[customer_name]</td>
          <td>$data[position]</td>
          <td>$data[branch]</td>
          <td>$data[start_IT]</td>
          <td>$data[group_section]</td>
          <td>$data[pic_handle]</td>
          <td>$data[pic_group_section]</td>

        </tr>

      </table>";
    }
```

I try send it and I get email but my query result just show 1 row and another row not showing.

Comment: Add complete Email code

Comment: I did @AmitGupta

Comment: What is coming in email?

Comment: You forgot the put a ';' at the end.

Comment: my query result but just 1 row, and another row not showing @AmitGupta

Comment: @Forbs is right. I think your issue must resolve now. Add semi colon ';' at the end of </table>";

Comment: I just forget type in here, but my code already use semi colon ';' at the end of </table>"; @Forbs

Comment: ohhh ok. You mean to say just first row is showing in loop, other one's not coming?

Comment: First you need to get $mail->Body in while loop and then your email comes after while loop.

Comment: I will post answer to tell you how it must be done.

Comment: Yeah like my loop is not working, I don't know how to make my loop running. I already try in normal php function(not in email) and my loop working properly @AmitGupta

Comment: I posted the answer. Try like this.

Comment: I updated the answer. Your table also needs to be out of the while loop, only <tr> will repeat. Try and let me know if fine.

Comment: Just making up properties isn't going to help anything. `$mail->PORT = "25"` should be `$mail->Port = 25` - PHP is case sensitive, and Port should be an integer. By luck this won't change anything, but suggests you're not paying attention. `$mail->mailtype` simply doesn't exist. I can also see you've based your code on an obsolete example, so you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer too. If you want to send lots of messages, see how to do that efficiently in the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. Also, **why** are you using the long-obsolete `mysql` extension?

Comment: You also have no error handling at all. What are you going to do when your database connection or mail server connection fails to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Email object must not be repeat again and again in while loop. It must only come once in your page and in while loop you have to get complete details of $mail->Body like below:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "172.16.x.xx"; //my company host
$mail->PORT = "25";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->Username = "myemail@acc.co.id"; //my company email  
$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password
$mail->IsHTML(true); 

$mail->From = "myemail@acc.co.id";
$mail->FromName = "ITCareHelpdesk ACC";
$mail->AddAddress("myemail@gmail.com");                            
$mail->mailtype = "html";
$mail->Subject = "Weekly monitoring tiket open ITcare"; 

$query = mysql_query("this is my query");
$body .= "<table border=1>";
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      // I show my query result in `$mail->Body`
$body .= "
     <tr>
    <th>Ticket ID</th>
    <th>Kategori</th>
    <th>Sub kategori</th>                         
    <th>Deskripsi</th>                         
    <th>NPK</th>                         
    <th>Nama</th>                         
    <th>Posisi</th>                         
    <th>Branch</th>                         
    <th>Waktu mulai</th>                         
    <th>Group section</th>                         
    <th>Pic Handle</th>
    <th>Pic Group Section</th>                                                  
  </tr>
  <tr $color>
      <td>$data[TICKET_ID]</td>
      <td>$data[kategori]</td>
      <td>$data[sub_sub_sub_kategori]</td>
      <td>$data[description]</td>
      <td>$data[npk]</td>
      <td>$data[customer_name]</td>
      <td>$data[position]</td>
      <td>$data[branch]</td>
      <td>$data[start_IT]</td>
      <td>$data[group_section]</td>
      <td>$data[pic_handle]</td>
      <td>$data[pic_group_section]</td>
    </tr>";
}
$body .= "</table>";
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->send();
```

Comment: I try it but now my email was not sent

Comment: Email must come. There is only the $mail->Body part that change. Rest everything is same.

Comment: Add complete $mail->Body part after $mail->Subject

Comment: And at last add $mail->send();

Comment: You can also append all data in one variable like $body and then assign all to $mail->Body like I have done in my answer. It must surely work.

Comment: can I get ur email? can I send it to ur email?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things in the comments are correct but you are also creating a new mail object inside the loop. This will lead to a single email (the last one) being sent. This is your structure:

```
while(...) {
    // create a new object
    $obj = new Object();
    ... do stuff to $obj
    ... repeat, but never use $obj
}

// Guessing, now is where you do stuff with $obj, 
// but this will be the last $obj created
$obj->send();
```

I see two solutions, create, modify and use each object in the loop:

```
while(...) {
    // create a new object
    $obj = new Object();
    ... do stuff to $obj
    $obj->send(); 
}
```

Or create a single object, modify and build on it, then use the single object

```
// create a single object outside the loop
$obj = new Object();
while(...) {
    ... do stuff to $obj
}
// Send the single object
$obj->send();
```